# NotificationCenter observer calls plays multiple videos - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

I have different `UIView`s one on top of the other; each of them plays a video using `AVPlayer`
I need each video to be replayed at the end and in order to do so I use this code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidReachEnd), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem)

@objc fileprivate func playerDidReachEnd(){
 self.player.seek(to: .zero)
 self.player.play()
}
```

I noticed that when the selector is called, all the other players in the other `UIView`s start playing as well...
This is strange to me because I've set the object of the observer to be only the `self.player.currentItem`

How can I make only this `AVPlayer` play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that that code is in every one of those views. So when the notification is posted, all of those views are observers. So they all start playing.